# Specifying the keys to sort a list of strings

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list of strings in python by two values. What I came up with is:

```
import operator
l = ['A1 B2', 'A2 B2', 'A1 B3', 'A2 B1', 'A1 B1']
sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 4))
['A1 B1', 'A1 B2', 'A1 B3', 'A2 B1', 'A2 B2']
```

However, the position of the keys is relatively hardcoded and if the strings change to `['AA1 BB2', 'AA2 BB2', 'AA1 BB3', 'AA2 BB1', 'AA1 BB1']`, it will not work. Furthermore, the numbers may also be with more that one digit `['A1 B202', 'A2 B101', 'A1 B200', 'A2 B100', 'A1 B201']`.

How can I sort the list of strings by the two digits more elegantly?

Comment: So you want to sort by the two digits in each string, is that it? Can there ever be more than a single digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do third party modules work? You can use `natsort` with a key that splits and naturally sorts:

```
>>> import natsort
>>> natsort.natsorted(l, key=str.split)
['AA1 BB1', 'AA1 BB2', 'AA1 BB3', 'AA2 BB1', 'AA2 BB2']
```

You can install `natsort` with `pip`.

- Should work when there are more than one digit
- Should also work when there are more than two words per string.
- Should also work when the number is not at the end of the string

Sorting is done *naturally*, not *lexicographically* as in the other answers which coincidentally returns the same answer as a natural sort would, for the examples presented here.

Comment: I'm stealing your key. Also didn't know about the `natsort` library, very interesting

Comment: @user3483203 All good. Really handy library, I've used it a few times myself.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that python's sort is only coincidental here, ah you've covered that in your update

Answer (score 1):

Best is without lambda:

```
>>> l=['A1 B202', 'A2 B101', 'A1 B200', 'A2 B100', 'A1 B201']
>>> sorted(l,key=str.split)
['A1 B200', 'A1 B201', 'A1 B202', 'A2 B100', 'A2 B101']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['A1 B202', 'A2 B101', 'A1 B200', 'A2 B100', 'A1 B201']
l = [" ".join(i) for i in sorted(i.split() for i in l)]
```

Sorry for Errolrs writen on mobile

Comment: Okay, now in the list, it contains the strings that are split, not the regular values

Comment: Oh i'm not home but just join All the list could someone do it for me ;)

Comment: Well okay then.